# Android Actionbar Spinning Samsung Galaxy 3 FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-appcompat, spinning

I'm adding the Compatibility Library V7 in a project, following the Android-Developers Blog:

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

The action bar has been working well since the beginning, all fine. But now, I've just seen something weird only in Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.0.4.

All Activities, which extend **ActionBarActivity**, where I need to show  "**setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility**" are showing immediately the Spinning, without any call to "**setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility**". 
I've checked that it's only appearing when I add the below line in "*onCreate*" to show the spinning icon.

> supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

Do you know why the spinning icon appear for itself? it's only happening in this device (Samsung S3)

By the way, I have all compatibility libraries up to date.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, on ICS (4.0), the progress indicators are shown by default when requesting the feature. This was fixed in JellyBean, see [this commit](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/45b075dd5cef54ed3412115ee199df1db1c90528).

As a workaround, you can always call `setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility` anyway and set it to `GONE` when you don't need it.

Comment: I know that the easiest solution would be adding setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false). But, from my point of view it's an extra work, are there any other way to set it GONE by default? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Not as far as I know. Maybe someone with better knowledge could help, I'd be interested in that as well ;)